# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined using PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I revised my code but I can not find the error, which seems simple, but I can not see anything from looking at the code. Can anyone help me? thank you very much.

This and the code for updating the record

```
// update modelo
public function alteraModelo($modelo){

    try{    
        // monta consulta SQL para atualização do registro
        $sql = "UPDATE modelos SET 

                    nome =          :nome,
                    fone =          :fone,
                    email =         :email,
                    face =          :face,
                    altura =        :altura,
                    peso =          :peso,
                    idade =         :idade,
                    categoria =     :categoria,
                    data_fotos =            :data_fotos";

                    if($_FILES['foto1']['size'] > 0){
                        $sql .= "foto1 = :foto1,";
                    }
                    if($_FILES['foto2']['size'] > 0){
                        $sql .= "foto2 = :foto2,";
                    }
                    if($_FILES['foto3']['size'] > 0){
                        $sql .= "foto3 = :foto3,";
                    }
                    if($_FILES['foto4']['size'] > 0){
                        $sql .= "foto4 = :foto4,";
                    }
                    if($_FILES['foto5']['size'] > 0){
                        $sql .= "foto5 = :foto5,";
                    }
                    if($_FILES['foto6']['size'] > 0){
                        $sql .= "foto6 = :foto6,";
                    }
                    $sql .="link_video =    :link_video
                        WHERE id =  :id";

        // prepara consulta para o PDO
        $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);

        $data = Util::dataToSql($modelo['data_fotos']);

        // seta os parametros
        $stmt->bindParam(":data_fotos", $data);
        $stmt->bindParam(":nome", $modelo['nome']);
        $stmt->bindParam(":fone", $modelo['fone']);
        $stmt->bindParam(":email", $modelo['email']);
        $stmt->bindParam(":face", $modelo['face']);
        $stmt->bindParam(":altura", $modelo['altura']);
        $stmt->bindParam(":peso", $modelo['peso']);
        $stmt->bindParam(":idade", $modelo['idade']);
        $stmt->bindParam(":link_video", $modelo['link_video']);
        $stmt->bindParam(":categoria", $modelo['categoria']);

        if($_FILES['foto1']['size'] > 0){
            //Se a foto for atualizada
            $registro_antigo = $this->getModeloById($modelo['id']);
            //Remove o arquivo
            @unlink($registro_antigo['foto1']);

            $arquivo1 = "upload/" . date('YmdHis') . "_" . $_FILES['foto1']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto1']['tmp_name'], APPLICATION_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . ".." . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $arquivo1);

            $stmt->bindParam(":foto1", $arquivo1);
        }

        if($_FILES['foto2']['size'] > 0){
            //Se a foto for atualizada
            $registro_antigo = $this->getModeloById($modelo['id']);
            //Remove o arquivo
            @unlink($registro_antigo['foto2']);

            $arquivo2 = "upload/" . date('YmdHis') . "_" . $_FILES['foto2']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto2']['tmp_name'], APPLICATION_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . ".." . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $arquivo2);

            $stmt->bindParam(":foto2", $arquivo2);
        }

        if($_FILES['foto3']['size'] > 0){
            //Se a foto for atualizada
            $registro_antigo = $this->getModeloById($modelo['id']);
            //Remove o arquivo
            @unlink($registro_antigo['foto3']);

            $arquivo3 = "upload/" . date('YmdHis') . "_" . $_FILES['foto3']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto3']['tmp_name'], APPLICATION_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . ".." . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $arquivo3);

            $stmt->bindParam(":foto3", $arquivo3);
        }

        if($_FILES['foto4']['size'] > 0){
            //Se a foto for atualizada
            $registro_antigo = $this->getModeloById($modelo['id']);
            //Remove o arquivo
            @unlink($registro_antigo['foto4']);

            $arquivo4 = "upload/" . date('YmdHis') . "_" . $_FILES['foto4']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto4']['tmp_name'], APPLICATION_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . ".." . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $arquivo4);

            $stmt->bindParam(":foto4", $arquivo4);
        }

        if($_FILES['foto5']['size'] > 0){
            //Se a foto for atualizada
            $registro_antigo = $this->getModeloById($modelo['id']);
            //Remove o arquivo
            @unlink($registro_antigo['foto5']);

            $arquivo5 = "upload/" . date('YmdHis') . "_" . $_FILES['foto5']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto5']['tmp_name'], APPLICATION_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . ".." . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $arquivo5);

            $stmt->bindParam(":foto5", $arquivo5);
        }

        if($_FILES['foto6']['size'] > 0){
            //Se a foto for atualizada
            $registro_antigo = $this->getModeloById($modelo['id']);
            //Remove o arquivo
            @unlink($registro_antigo['foto6']);

            $arquivo6 = "upload/" . date('YmdHis') . "_" . $_FILES['foto6']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto6']['tmp_name'], APPLICATION_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . ".." . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $arquivo6);

            $stmt->bindParam(":foto6", $arquivo6);
        }

        $stmt->bindParam(":id", $modelo['id']);
        // atualiza registro
        $stmt->execute();

    } catch (Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();

        }
}
```

Comment: You need to add a comma after `data_fotos =            :data_fotos";` - you're catted more SQL on to the end of `$sql` on the following lines, but it'll be added directly onto the end of `:data_fotos`.

Comment: yes you were right, it was just a "comma" was missing. But I think my eyes were tired and his was to the point, or rather direct a comma. thank you very much

Comment: Sometimes it just takes an extra set of eyes. I'm glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

> I can not see anything from looking at the code.

That's right. **Nobody** is doing it that way. A code intended to be **run**, not to be admired.

Look, you are writing a program to build an SQL query. But what is the result of the program? Do you know it? No.
Why no to tell your code to echo the query out and see, if everything all right?

Why not to echo all the bound variables as well, and compare them to the parameters in the query?

Also, your idea of storing photos in a database is wrong.
There should never be no enumerated fields in the table. If you have one - you are doing something wrong. **Another table** have to be used to store all the repeated similar data.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but first I am not very knowledgeable on the subject, but I know what you're doing so, because my code does exactly what has to be done, and if you were so expert could have helped me so just looking at the code and see that I was just missing a comma, such as the friend above .... ie my rookie mistake